# Timestamping Using Date Class Java

Tags: java, time

I am trying to use the Date class to get the current time each time my loop executes. So far I have:

```
Date timeNow = new Date();

while(true){

System.out.println(timeNow.getTime()); //prints current time

    Thread.sleep(10000);//sleep 10 secounds

}
```

When the time is reprinted it just shows the same time every print instead of being 10 seconds later. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Date` is just a snapshot of the date/time it was created, you need to create a new instance each time you want to get the new date/time

Comment: The description for the Date class is as follows: `Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.` So that allocation time is above your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created timeNow outside of the while loop. The time for this object is captured at construction time. When you move it within the scope of the while loop, you'll get a new object every time which represents the time it was created.

```
  while(true) {
    Date timeNow = new Date();
    System.out.println(timeNow.getTime()); //prints current time
    Thread.sleep(10000);//sleep 10 secounds
  }
```

Note that the default constructor of `Date` is equivalent to..

```
Date timeNow = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `Date myDate = new Date()` you create a `Date` object with the current system time.

Anytime you call `myDate.getTime()` you will get the same output, the time as at whenever you created the object.

To see a different time, you would need to create a new `Date` object after each `Thread.sleep(10000)`, like this:

```
while(true) {
    Date myDate = new Date()
    System.out.println(myDate.getTime()); //prints current time
    Thread.sleep(10000);//sleep 10 seconds
}
```